# form needs submit to be pressed twice in order to submit using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

There are a few similar questions to mine out there but mine is different since I am not using the validate function inside a submit (in fact not at all) and also I am not using ajax.

I have a form and the submit looks like this:

```
(function ($, settings, undefined) {
    var hasSubmitted = false;
    $(function () {
       $("form").submit(function () {
            var theForm = $(this);
            var cancelClicked = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true].cancel").length > 0;
            if (cancelClicked || (theForm.valid() && !myOtherRequirements())) {
                hasSubmitted = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
      }
})(jQuery, settings);
```

The clicked true is an attribute that is added on an click event:

```
 $("form input[type=submit]").click(function () {
        $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
        $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
    });
```

As you've guessed, I have to press the submit button twice to get the form to submit but I can't understand why. The first time it does absolutely nothing. There's no alerts hitting, or network activity on the debugger. The events **.submit** and **.click** are not fired at all.

The other forms with this structure seem to work without this problem.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

Found the problem. There was another unrelated ajax call executing in the same page in the background and the submit wouldn't work unless that other ajax call was complete. Makes sense!

Comment: Debug your script (with `debugger;` statement inserted into that handler, or with breakpoints) to see values of these expressions in `if` clause.

Comment: What is the `[clicked=true]` selector in your jQuery constructor? I've never seen that before, and a quick search didn't find any docs about it.

Comment: I've added clarification regarding "clicked=true". It's a custom attribute to keep track if the button was clicked or not. It could very well be the problem